# field separator in awk

Tags: parsing, awk

I have the following "input.file":

```
10      61694   rs546443136     T       G       .       PASS    RefPanelAF=0.0288539;AC=0;AN=1186;INFO=1.24991e-09      GT:DS:GP        0/0:0.1:0.9025,0.095,0.0025     0/0:0.1:0.9025,0.095,0.0025     0/0:0.1:0.9025,0.095,0.0025
```

My desired output.file is:

```
0.1, 0.1, 0.1
```

Using an awk script called "parse.awk":

```
BEGIN {FS = ":"}
{for (i = 4; i <= NF; i += 2) printf ("%s%c", $i, i +2 <= NF ? "," : "\n ");}
```

which is invocated with:

```
awk -f parse.awk <input.file >output.file
```

my current output.file is as follows:

```
0.1,0.1,0.1
```

i.e. no spaces.

Changing pasre.awk to:

```
BEGIN {FS = ":"}
{for (i = 4; i <= NF; i += 2) printf ("%s%c", $i, i +2 <= NF ? ", " : "\n ");}
```

did not change the output.file. What change(s) to parse.awk will yield the desired output.file?

Comment: Do you always only have 1 line in your input? If you can have multiple then you should post sample input/output with at least 2.

Comment: This might help: `awk '{print $4,$6,$8}' FS=':' OFS=', ' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=', ' '{
  for (i = 4; i <= NF; i += 2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i < NF-1 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
```

```
0.1, 0.1, 0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. Written and tested it in
https://ideone.com/e26q7u

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS = ":"}
val!=""{ print val; val=""}
{for (i = 4; i <= NF; i += 2){
  val=(val==""?"":val", ")$i
  }
}
END{
  if(val!=""){
    print val
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you changed the output separator from a single comma (`","`) to comma with space (`", "`); you did not change the format string from `%c` to `%s`. So that is how to fix your script:

```
BEGIN {FS = ":"}
{for (i = 4; i <= NF; i += 2) printf ("%s%s", $i, i +2 <= NF ? ", " : "\n ");}
#                                         ^ Change this
```